# WooCommerce order notification email dependent on checkout field selection

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Our client would like the WooCommerce order notification email to be sent to the branch selected via

https://mrk.imaginethis.co.za/shop/ (add a product to the cart) > go to https://mrk.imaginethis.co.za/checkout/ > select “Collect” on the right-hand side under the “Courier or Collect Item/s?” heading.

Please let me know if this is possible with an existing WordPress plugin, and if not, if there are any existing code that we can use in order to achieve this.

It would be ideal, of course, if any coding changes to the default WooCommerce files aren't overridden when we update WooCommerce (hence the reason why a plugin would be ideal).

Comment: Yes it's possible with custom code, but you should provide in your question your code intent as StackOverFlow is code oriented… Also please note that asking for plugin recommendations is off topic in StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the *advanced notifications* extension for woocommerce.

Once you have this you can then add a notification for each of the branches. Assuming you are using a different sipping class for each branch you can use this as the trigger for the notification.

Have a look at the woocommerce page on advanced notifications.

- https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/advanced-notifications/

Comment: Thank you, Matthew. Will give it a try and report back.